# Backbone/thorax rendering child views failing

Tags: backbone.js, javascript

I'm trying to embed a child view with Backbone Thorax / Handlebars, my code is as follows:

View

```
child: new BunnyRabbitsListView(),
template: template,
render: function() {
  $(this.el).html(this.template({ child: this.child }));
}
```

Template

```
<div>{{view child}}</div>
```

BunnyRabbitsListView Template

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
```

I'm getting an error in my browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_helperName' of undefined
```

and the stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_helperName' of undefined thorax.js:948
getParent thorax.js:948
(anonymous function) thorax.js:983
(anonymous function) VM218:10
(anonymous function) handlebars.js:2212
(anonymous function) handlebars.js:2172
jQuery.extend.access jquery.js:849
jQuery.fn.extend.html jquery.js:6015
collection.fetch.success index.js:20
options.(anonymous function) thorax.js:2931
(anonymous function) thorax.js:2894
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:78
(anonymous function) thorax.js:2892
options.success thorax.js:1405
options.success backbone.js:856
fire jquery.js:1017
self.fireWith jquery.js:1127
done jquery.js:8021
callback jquery.js:855
```

and this is `index.js:20` FWIW

```
$(this.el).html(this.template({ child: this.child }));
```

Comment: Isn't `template` a function? like: `this.$el.html(this.template())`...also, how `child` is used in your code? To me i think instantiating a view in the view definition is weird...shouldn't it be `child: function () { return new ServiceProvidersListView();}`  so you won't have the same child for each view?

Comment: it would make sense, and I've changed the code since to reflect this (updating main post now, template is a function which requires things to be passed to it, but for this example the fact that this.child is one view isn't an issue, it still breaks.) but this is not the source of my issue it seems... :(

Answer (score 2):

I've created a working example on embedding child view with parent view in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAc8X/1/).
I'm not using render method though. Let me know whether it helps.

Here is the working code:

```
var BunnyRabbitsListView = Thorax.View.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile("<p>Hello World</p>")
});

var ParentView = Thorax.View.extend({
  child: new BunnyRabbitsListView(),
  template: Handlebars.compile("{{view child}}")
});

var parentView = new ParentView();
parentView.appendTo('body');
```